# iCloud Storage and Macbook space issues

Tags: xcode, icloud

This is really frustrating to me. I have an old MacBook with a 256 GB hard drive and I have 1TB of iCloud space.
I can't install XCode because it is telling me that I don't have enough space, which is true because I only see 22 GB of free space.
I am trying to free up space and no matter what I do I can't seem to get more than 24 GB space free.
I used Storage Management and I see most of the space is in Documents which is synch-ed with iCloud.
The whole point of me having iCloud is so I can free my local space but I can't seem to release the local space ...It is as if iCloud is expecting me to have local storage still available to mirror iCloud.

However, if I delete my local files, I lose those in iCloud as well, as the iCloud thinks I must not need these files.
My question, I am obviously missing something here. It can't be this way

Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove local downloads of your iCloud documents.

Open finder -> Open iCloud Drive -> Find a downloaded document/folder -> Context click -> Remove Download.

[image]

In this way, your documents will still be in iCloud, but the local copies will be deleted.

Comment: I don't see "Remove Download" option?

Comment: @JimGreen You might do that to a folder with an icon on it (such as "Pages"). You cannot do that.

Comment: I don't think I explained my problem well. I don't see "Remove Download" in most of the iCloud folders which make me believe I have most of these NOT downloaded...I still see these taking up storage

Comment: @JimGreen If they are not downloaded, you will see "Download Now" option and an icon of a cloud and a down-arrow. Did you see them?

Comment: @JimGreen I'm seeing the same thing on an iCloud volume; some small files have the Remove Download option, but the problematic large video files don't have "Remove Download", nor "Download Now", yet they play, so they clearly are downloaded.  Did you ever get this solved?